# Weird Behavior Deploying Azure Cloud Service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I have a very weird issue deploying an azure cloud Service. I have 1 Web Role with 5 instances and 1 Cache Role with 2 instances.

When I deploy my MVC 5 WebRole from the Azure Portal, deploying starts on the first web instance, then it tells me that the "The role could not be started" due to an error and stops processing the other instances. I did an RDP to the failed instance and truly the MVC application throws an error that it can't find a certain view file "The layout page "..." could not be found at the following path", even though the view in the path specified does exist. So I did an iisreset and the application worked. after I manually fixed the issue the deployment continues to the next instance and the failed instance becomes "Ready".

Anyone has an idea why things don't deploy smoothly anymore or why an iisreset is necessary?

This is relatively recent, around a month.

My environment is:

1. .NET Framework 4.5.1
2. MVC 5
3. Azure SDK 2.4 for VS 2013

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does your app run successfully locally in the emulator? Have you tried both the express and full emulators? For your scenario, you should be using the full emulator but I'd start with the express first since it will load faster.

Comment: Ya, it works perfectly on both emulators

Comment: How are you deploying your app? Is it possibly a permissions issue with the account under which the worker process is running?

Comment: Pretty simple actually, I use the default IIS AppPool settings and identity. I upload a package to the blob storage and update the service from this package, using the web portal.

Comment: This is rather strange. I assume you are targeting OS Family 4. If not, do so. As last resort, try running the web role in elevated mode: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg557553.aspx - Runtime element, executionContext attribute. Running in elevated should solve any permissions. But I am more wondering whether you have a race condition - Web role instances trying to access Cache before it is fully ready.

Comment: Silly question, did you check that you configured your Azure to be targeting the correct framework? In your case, I think is the latest, `.NET Framework 4.5.1`.

Comment: @astaykov I did set the OS family to 4, will try to set the elevated mode and try. not sure about the race condition though, the exact same setup was there for months, it just started acting up lately.

Comment: @Kutyel, I hope it was silly, I wouldn't have bothered to post here and add a bounty. but to answer ur question, Yes, I did set the target framework to 4.5.1

Comment: @Tamim Salem sorry, I meant that my question was silly :)

Comment: @Kutyel Oh sorry too, the statement wasn't very clear to me, no worries :)

Comment: @TamimSalem, so what happened with OSFamily 4 ?

Comment: @astaykov the service was already set to OS family 4 already, its not related.

Comment: 1- I'd recommend trying to look for more than one source of logs, one of them will eventually get you an idea on what is causing this, take a look here for what you can use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/hh771389.aspx 2- Try to do the deployments on new cloud services and see if you get the same error, maybe something gets stuck on the update process? 3- If all hope is lost, I'd open a ticket with Microsoft and ask them to do some troubleshooting from their side.

Comment: Have you tried publishing to Azure directly through Visual Studio? I find that it saves a lot of clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FINALLY!! I found the issue and fixed it.

I had a Local Storage Resources to store temporary files and local file caches for certain components, and was configured to reset on role restart. One of the components (Lucene.NET for azure) was locking the files in that local storage, causing the problem on deployment that needed to to IIS reset to release the lock.

I configured the component to cache the files on Windows temp storage instead of the Local Resource and things worked out.